# Who is the strongest esper in One Punch Man?

Tags: one-punch-man

In One Punch Man there are several espers. One of them claims to be stronger than Tatsumaki. Is this true? Who is the strongest esper in One Punch Man?

Comment: Tatsumaki is the strongest esper shown so far. I can't seem to recall that an esper is claiming to be stronger than Tatsumaki. Who is it you're referring to? Is it Geryuganshoop?

Comment: I just saw that, I dont remember why I wrote that, I think Psykos claims so in the webcomic. Probably Geryuganshoop claimed the same in the anime, I dont recall

Comment: Yes, I just watched the fight between Geryuganshoop  and Saitama, Geryuganshoop  claims he is in the anime. But I think I wrote it because of Psykos and I didnt want to mention her saying so for spoilers

Comment: Lel there's always spoiler indications.

Comment: We need to know their power levels to make comparisons, and I haven't seen any scouters show up yet, so it's all conjecture.

Answer (score 1):

Update: Gyoro Gyoro(Monster who created Orochi, the king of monsters) and described by Tatsumaki as a "Bag of Flesh" was actually as said, a doll controlled by an esper. While that esper goes by the name Psykos, nothing is revealed about her yet in the manga (Much less the anime).

Spoiler from the Webcomics:

> In the Webcomics of One Punch Man (The most original version which is far ahead of the manga) created by the group One, shows the fight between Psykos and Tatsumaki. It is then revealed that Psykos was once a student/part of Fubuki's group and was nearly overpowered by Tatsumaki until the Cadets of the Monster Association attacked Tatsumaki. While defending herself against the Cadets, she didn't realize that Psykos was about to attack her until it was too late. After Tatsumaki was defeated by the surprise attack from Psykos, Fubuki comes in and attacks Psykos, which she comes out of victorious.

In conclusion, we could say that... (Spoilers)

> Fubuki is the strongest because she won against Psykos who defeated the "strongest" esper Tatsumaki, but seeing as Psykos was weakened and Fubuki had focused her training on defense against overwhelming psychic strength, they all were strong in their own ways. Tatsumaki had the overwhelming resistance and raw power to crush enemies, while Psykos and Fubuki used subtle techniques like doll manipulation (Gyoro Gyoro), and scattering the psychic waves respectively. However, as User Gary Andrews 30 pointed out, Tatsumaki was shown to be more powerful in several more instances and Fubuki's simple scattering technique didn't count as power.

Psykos's character page:

> https://onepunchman.fandom.com/wiki/Psykos

Comment: Sorry, this is incorrect. Psykos was simply mad at Fubuki and fell right into her trap. She's at the very least, a top tier A class hero and nowhere close to Tatsumaki. She needed Tatasumaki's help to defeat Demon Fan and Super S who are both demon level threats.

Comment: That's true, but we can't tell that for sure, because she did defeat Psykos. That's why I claimed above that they are all strong in their own different ways. Of course Fubuki couldn't compare to Tatsumaki in raw power, but she does use a subtle way to win.

Comment: Tatsumaki is much stronger than Psykos and Fubuki as well.

Comment: https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/52688/31104

Answer (score 0):

OP specifies in the comment that they are referring to claims made by Gyoro-Gyoro.  Eventually Gyoro-Gyoro encounters Tatsumaki and they battle. The following will be spoilers for anime-only people, but at this point the encounter has happened in the manga, and is essentially the same as in the webcomic.

---

Turns out it's all arrogant bluster by someone who didn't grasp the true depths of Tatsumaki's power.

[image: Gyoro-Gyoro gets wrecked]

> Though as mentioned in Sphinx's answer, in the webcomic Psykos, the real identity of Gyoro-Gyoro, tactically outmaneuvers Tatsumaki in a group battle by landing a sneak attack to disable her while she's about to crush several other Dragon rank monsters.  This isn't a victory by esper ability, but one can certainly give her credit for knowing how to find and exploit an opening in Tatsumaki's defenses.  Sphinx's answer is otherwise misleading as regards Fubuki, as in the same chapter her special technique is described it is pointed out that Tatsumaki mastered it as a child and has since adapted it into a weapon. That's the usual story of things: every new height Fubuki reaches is something Tatsumaki has achieved since childhood. Fubuki needed it to deal with Psykos's superior power.  There's no indication that Tatsumaki ever needed anything more than her usual barrier to completely negate that power, though she's certainly aware of how to use that technique to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Tatsumaki, and by a wide margin.

geryuganshoop + Melzargard + Groribas (Boros's three lieutenants) together have been stated to have very little chance against Orochi, even with prep time.

Gyoro gyoro is weaker than Orochi, but was just a meat puppet controlled by Psykos, Psykos plus a psychic enhancing drug was seemingly able to fight with Orochi at least mentally and has shown more impressive abilities than geryuganshoop and is probably stronger.

Orochi + Psykos + psychic enhancing drug + a boost by god + energy sucked up from the planet was absolutely outclassed by Tatsumaki.

The question isn't whether Geryuganshoop could fight Tatsumaki, it's whether or not Boros could.